# Show special price discount % in Opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I want to Show special price discount % on category page(product listing) as well as product page. Like

```
<h3><?php echo (($price[0]-$special[0])/$price[0])*100 ?>% Discount</h3>
```

But how can we fetch the price without currency code on product as well category page?
Or

May be we can also fetch selected currency, and then exclude it from $price and $special.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Category Controller :**

> File Path : catalog\controller\product\category.php

A. find this line

```
$special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
```

after add

```
$disPercentage = ((($result['price']-$result['special'])/$result['price']) * 100);
```

B. find this line

```
$special = false;
```

after add

```
$disPercentage = false;
```

C. find this line

```
'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
```

after add

```
'disPercentage' => $disPercentage,
```

**2. Category View Page:**

> File Path : catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl

A. find this line

```
<h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
```

after add

```
<?php if ($product['special']) { ?>
    <h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $product['disPercentage']; ?>% Discount</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

**[image: Product Listing Screenshot :]**

**3. Product Controller :**

> File Path : catalog\controller\product\product.php

A. find this line

```
$data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
```

after add

```
$data['disPercentage'] = ((($product_info['price']-$product_info['special'])/$product_info['price']) * 100);
```

B. find this line

```
$data['special'] = false;
```

after add

```
$data['disPercentage'] = false;
```

**4. Product View Page :**

> File Path : catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl

A.find this line

```
<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
```

after add

```
<?php if ($special) { ?>
   <h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $disPercentage; ?>% Discount</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: Product page Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

in the corresponding controller file find:

```
$data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
```

replace with:

```
$data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency'], true, false);
```

The same with a special price...

Comment: @ Anmol singh If the answer was useful you can mark it.

Comment: @Anmolsingh you are satisfied KB's answer ??